# Javascript canvas not displaying in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-canvas

I've run into this problem on a few occasions but I can't seem to find a solid answer or solution to the problem.

I created a site that uses two canvases layered on top of each other which display properly in Chrome, but in Firefox only one of the canvases will display. Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var interval;
    var width, height;

// ------------- SETUP ----------------------    
    window.onload = function() {
        width = document.width;
        height = document.height;
    setupC1();
        setupC2();
}

function setupC1(){
    canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas1.width = document.width;
    canvas1.height = document.height;
        canvas1.style.position = "absolute";
        canvas1.style.top = "0px";
        canvas1.style.left = "0px";
        canvas1.style.zIndex = "-2";
    document.body.appendChild(canvas1);
    ctx = canvas1.getContext("2d");
        interval = setInterval(draw, 50);
}

    function setupC2(){
    canvas2 = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas2.width = "399";
    canvas2.height = "274";
        canvas2.style.position = "absolute";
        canvas2.style.top = (window.innerHeight/2)-100 +"px";
        canvas2.style.left = (window.innerWidth/2)-200 +"px";
        canvas2.style.zIndex = "-1";
    document.body.appendChild(canvas2);
    ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
        interval = setInterval(gun, 50);
}


// ------------- DRAW ----------------------     
    function draw() {

    var x = Math.round(Math.random()*window.innerWidth);
    var y = Math.round(Math.random()*window.innerHeight);
    function rndColor() {
        return '#' + ('00000' + (Math.random() * 16777216 << 0).toString(16)).substr(-6);
    }
    //draw here

        ctx.strokeStyle=rndColor();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/2);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();            

    }

function gun(){
    ctx2.fillStyle="#000000";
        ctx2.strokeStyle="#000000";
        ctx2.beginPath();
        ctx2.moveTo(51, 28);
        ctx2.lineTo(66, 28);
        ctx2.lineTo(71, 19);
        ctx2.lineTo(75, 19);
        ctx2.lineTo(77, 28);
        ctx2.lineTo(191, 28);
        ctx2.lineTo(191, 30);
        ctx2.lineTo(238, 30);
        ctx2.lineTo(238, 28);
        ctx2.lineTo(350, 28);
        ctx2.lineTo(355, 23);
        ctx2.lineTo(358, 28);
        ctx2.lineTo(368, 28);
        ctx2.lineTo(368, 36);
        ctx2.lineTo(373, 36);
        ctx2.lineTo(374, 59);
        ctx2.lineTo(368, 59);
        ctx2.lineTo(368, 69);
        ctx2.lineTo(371, 69);
        ctx2.lineTo(371, 77);
        ctx2.lineTo(368, 80);
        ctx2.lineTo(368, 95);
        ctx2.lineTo(265, 102);
        ctx2.lineTo(265, 153);
        ctx2.lineTo(164, 153);
        ctx2.lineTo(169, 141);
        ctx2.lineTo(249, 141);
        ctx2.lineTo(249, 103);
        ctx2.lineTo(198, 106);
        ctx2.bezierCurveTo(192, 106, 195, 135, 200, 137);
        ctx2.lineTo(194, 139);
        ctx2.bezierCurveTo(190, 136, 178, 108, 180, 106);
        ctx2.lineTo(169, 143);
        ctx2.lineTo(156, 156);
        ctx2.lineTo(157, 176);
        ctx2.lineTo(143, 190);
        ctx2.lineTo(144, 208);
        ctx2.lineTo(129, 222);
        ctx2.lineTo(129, 242);
        ctx2.lineTo(120, 242);
        ctx2.lineTo(120, 255);
        ctx2.lineTo(42, 246);
        ctx2.lineTo(48, 233);
        ctx2.lineTo(37, 231);
        ctx2.lineTo(25, 220);
        ctx2.lineTo(75, 113);
        ctx2.bezierCurveTo(75, 90, 55, 85, 46, 83);
        ctx2.closePath();
        ctx2.fill();
        ctx2.stroke();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I feel like I may have heard about potential firefox issues with using negative z-indexes, could that really be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no `width` or `height` properties on the document object in the specs, so `document.width` ends up as undefined, and so does `document.height`.  So you're setting your canvas1 to have a width and height of 0, which is the number undefined converts to.

You may want to use one of the things listed at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.width#Alternatives and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.height#Alternatives